# Invalid operands to binary expression when using unordered_map?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find if my character hash table contains the first character of a string:

```
string minWindow(string s, string t) {
    unordered_map<char, int> charFinder;
    for (int i = 0; i < t.length(); ++i) {
        charFinder[t[i]] = 0;
    }
    cout << charFinder.find(s[0]) == charFinder.end() << endl;
    return "hi";
}
```

But I get this error for some reason. This doesn't make any sense to me. Anyone have any ideas?

```
Line 8: Char 14: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'std::unordered_map<char, int, std::hash<char>, std::equal_to<char>, std::allocator<std::pair<const char, int> > >::iterator' (aka '_Node_iterator<std::pair<const char, int>, __constant_iterators::value, __hash_cached::value>'))
        cout << charFinder.find(s[1]) == charFinder.end() << endl;
        ~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/cstddef:124:5:
note: candidate function template not viable: no known conversion from 'std::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') to 'std::byte' for 1st argument
    operator<<(byte __b, _IntegerType __shift) noexcept
    ^
```

I cutoff the rest of the long error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `operator<<` has a higher precedence than `operator==`, so your `cout` expression:

```cpp
cout << charFinder.find(s[0]) == charFinder.end() << endl;
```

Is being evaluated as if you had written it like this:

```cpp
(cout << charFinder.find(s[0])) == (charFinder.end() << endl);
```

The compiler error is complaining about passing the `std::unordered_map` itself to `operator<<`, which is not what you intended.  Look at the error message more carefully, that is exactly what it is pointing out.  There is no `operator<<` for `std::ostream` that takes a `std::unordered_map` as input.

To fix this, you need to use parenthesis explicitly to tell the compiler what you really want, eg:

```cpp
cout << (charFinder.find(s[0]) == charFinder.end()) << endl;
```

Otherwise, use a `bool` variable instead:

```cpp
bool notFound = charFinder.find(s[0]) == charFinder.end();
cout << notFound << endl;
```

In C++20, you can use [`std::unordered_map::contains()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/contains) instead:

```cpp
cout << charFinder.contains(s[0]) << endl;
```

---

That being said, since you are not actually using the character counts at all, you should use [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) instead of `std::unordered_map`, eg:

```cpp
string minWindow(string s, string t) {
    set<char> charFinder;
    for (int i = 0; i < t.length(); ++i) {
        charFinder.insert(t[i]);
    }
    //
    // alternatively:
    // set<char> charFinder(t.begin(), t.end());

    cout << (charFinder.find(s[0]) == charFinder.end()) << endl;
    //
    // alternatively:
    // bool notFound = charFinder.find(s[0]) == charFinder.end();
    // cout << notFound << endl;
    //
    // alternatively:
    // cout << charFinder.contains(s[0]) << endl;

    return "hi";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with this statement :

```
cout << charFinder.find(s[0]) == charFinder.end() << endl;
```

stream insertion operator, `<<` has higher precedence than equality operator, `==`.

The statement is same as :

```
((cout << charFinder.find(s[0])) == charFinder.end()) << endl;
```

The overloaded operator `<<` of `std::cout` returns a reference to `std::cout`.

When compiler encounters that you are comparing a `std::ostream` object (`std::cout`) with an `iterator` which is returned by `std::unordered_map.end()` it issues an error as `std::ostream` does not have an overloaded operator `==` to compare itself with an `iterator`.